# Merging two drives in Windows 10 without losing their contents?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

In order to avoid fragmentation - As i intend on making a Linux partition in the near future - i wish to merge my `C:` and `D:` drives, which are sequential, into a single drive. However, every method i've came across has the downside of wiping my `D:` drive in order to do it.
Should i just manually copy and paste my entire `D:` drive into my `C:` drive, or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: yeah thats not going to work. writing the file data is meaningless if the Filesytem metadata isn't merged with the existing volume filesystem. just copy and paste the files. and don't worry so much about fragmentation, unless you have a very specific usecase that requires the updating of huge numbers of files on a mostly full disk. fragmentation is a very 2001 kind of issue, and especially with non-mechanical disks like SSDs, you are wasting your time worrying about it too much for standard enthusiast/home usecases.

Answer (score -1):

Use partition tools.

I recommend Aomei and EaseUS.